# Bounding the integral of the reciprocal of a complex polynomial

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, polynomials, contour-integration

So, I would like to bound $\int_{C_R} \frac{1}{P(z)} dz$ where 
$C_R$ is the circle radius R centred at the origin, and $P(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $N=0,1,...,n$ i also want to deduce for what values of N the integral will disappear as $R\rightarrow \infty$

My solution is as follows but i don't know if my argument is rigorous enough.

So in the proof of fundamental theorem of algebra we showed in class that $|\frac{1}{P(z)}|< \frac{2}{|a_n|R^n}$ , parametrised the circle: $\gamma(t)=Re^{it}$ for $t\in [0,2\pi]$, $\gamma'(t)=Rie^{it}$ and let $f(z)=\frac{1}{p(z)}$ then the integral goes as follows:

$$\int_{c_R} f(z)dz < \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{2iRe^{it}}{|a_n|R^n}dt = \frac{2i}{|a_n|R^{n-1}} [\frac{e^{it}}{i}]^{2\pi}_{0}$$
which goes to 0 for all values of R.

Which doesn't seem quite right, have I chose the wrong bound? the integral i defined also goes to 0, but I'm thinking for $n=0,1$. Could i say that, on $C_R$, $f(z) < R$ so that would mean q factor of R out and instead of getting $0$ i'd just get the bound $\frac{2i}{|a_n|R^{n-1}}$ which wouldn't go to $0$ for $n=0,1,2$ as $R\rightarrow \infty$

This is a homework question so please don't post a solution, suggestions and identification of errors would be a great help! Thank you!

Comment: I just saw that the integral is closed, so by Cauchy's theorem it will be $0$. could i just use the half circle and let $t\in [0,\pi]$?

Comment: no your proof that $\int_{C_R} \frac1{P(z)} dz \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$ is not correct. you need to write $\int_{C_R} \frac1{P(z)} dz < \int_{C_R} \frac1{|P(z)|} d|z| = \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{|P(R e^{it})|} R dt  < \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{|a_n| R^n} R dt \to 0$ whenever $n > 1$

Comment: and no the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) says a closed contour integral is $0$ whenever the integrated function is HOLOMORPHIC on and inside the contour. $\frac{1}{P(z)}$ has poles inside the contour when $R$ is large enough and $n \ne 0$... for computing it you'll need the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem